# How to confirm the header contains the keywords that I want?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<h1 class="page-header">Groups<span class="badge grp-cnt-badge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Total {{grpCnt}} Groups">{{grpCnt}}</span></h1>
```

As you could see, the header in page will display like a string **Groups** and there is a toolip(a count number) after it.

I do want to confirm if the **Groups** is always there. So I wrote like below:

```
it('Search the page header contains key words', function() {
var grpTitle = element(by.tagName('h1'));
expect(grpTitle.getText()).toBe('Groups');
 //Now report the error, becuase the real return value is like Group136 });
```

What I could do to let the `grpTitle` return **Groups** only.

Thanks.

Comment: by using something called a regular expression maybe?

Comment: How bout using expect(grpTitle.getText()). **toContain** ('Groups');?

Comment: @Amal, thanks. The easy way to use toContain. confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **toContain** instead of **toBe**

expect(grpTitle.getText()).toContain('Groups');

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Sakshi, it works for me. I didnot find toContain in protractor API, where i could find the note for it?

Comment: @BoykaZhu Protractor is not what is running your assertions, that would be something like Jasmine. If you are using Jasmine, you can find the documentation for `toContain` here http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. let me take a look at there.